# Why might Photos be "Unable to upload" certain image files?

Tags: icloud, photos

Just to be clear, I have masses of free space on iCloud. **This is not a storage space issue.**

I'm using Photos 7.0.

I have a variety of images in the "Unable to upload to iCloud" folder, and they don't appear on iCloud.

Photos itself seems to be perfectly happy with them. They are mostly `.tif` files of slide scans, and RAW Pentax `.pef` files.

Weirdly, I have previously been able to upload these items to iCloud, with an earlier version Photos.

Also weirdly, the "Unable to upload to iCloud Photos" condition for smart albums doesn't show the same items (or indeed any items).

There is no indication *why* there is a problem with these files. I am pretty sure that it's related to the file type or some metadata though. Is there:

- some way of finding out what the issue is?
- something that might remedy the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Likely a file format or colorSync profile issue. Export, re-import and then try to upload. Also see if [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8320858) helps. The smart album bit is strange, though.

Comment: Answers should be more than just links. Please include the relevant parts directly into your post so people don't have to jump off-site for the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this with Photos 8 on just a few photos. Duplicating them and deleting the originals resolved the issues.